# bring back eth0, consistent network device naming

Tags: network-interface, ethernet

I ran into a software licensing problem where in RHEL 7.x which now uses  **consistent network device naming** and or **biosdevname** and or **predictable network interface names**.  Software did not work having a network interface name of something like *enp0s31f6*, it wants to see *eth*.

so my network name for one network port off the motherboard is named `enp0s31f6`

I can modify `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb verbose ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"` however that doesn't reach the end goal after doing a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` and a `reboot` I still see *enp0s31f6*.

Not until doing `nmcli connection modify enp0s31f6 connection.interface-name eth0` followed by a `reboot` do i then see only `eth0` using `ifconfig` and everything works.

Is there a better and/or easier way of ensuring **eth** is the name of network interfaces?  Keeping in mind it's easy if it's just one so eth0, but when you have a quad nic card I simply want eth0..eth3 like in the good old days.

I thought having *eth0* and *eth1* and *eth2* and *eth3* was pretty good *consistent device network naming*.  Now I get *enp* this and *xyz* that for interface names :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried out udev some days ago, and didn't find out much. One thing in the end worked though:

`/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.ruleXXX`

I "renamed" that file and now I have `eth0`.

For restarting udev I think was udeavadm control -e.

Stopping is also very easy:

> Note that systemd-udevd.service contains Restart=always and so as a
>   result, this option restarts systemd-udevd. If you want to stop
>   systemd-udevd.service, please use the following: systemctl stop
>   systemd-udevd-control.socket systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
>   systemd-udevd.service

I was so desparate I pasted that -- it works! Then I found that file 80-net-link...

"# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update."

(I know. I'll rename it again)

It contains:

NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME}"

So I replaced `.rules` with `.ruleXXX`, and I have "eth0" again.